# How to get the free memory size (ram) of a virtual machine using JAVA

Tags: java, virtual-machine, ram

I'm trying to get the used percentage ram used on a virtual machine.

In local on my computer I achieve it by using :

`Double FreeRamSize = (double) mxBean.getFreePhysicalMemorySize()
 Double TotalRamSize = (double) mxBean.getTotalPhysicalMemorySize()`

And it works perfectly fine.
But if I deploy my app on a virtual machine, I will only have the total physical memory size and my FreeRamSize will always return 0. I didn't find any tips on internet.

Thank in advance for your help.

Comment: I don't know if I get completely the question, but there is no difference between physical and virtual machine by the programming perspective

Comment: What makes you think you will need to change how you access memory information for a virtual machine? Have you tried?

Comment: @FelicePollano Maybe I don't explain my problem correctly. I can't get the free physical memory size on my virtual machine. It will always rerturn 0. But i will get the total physical memory size. 
(In local on my computer I will have the both values).

Comment: @BooRadley One of my superior told me that, I didn't find any other way to do it when searching on internet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not need to modify the memory information code to run a virtual machine since the underlying differences between a virtual machine and physical machines RAM should be completely irrelevant to a Java process.

Just for kicks I ran this on my own virtual machine with no problems.

```
double GiB = Math.pow(2, 30);
OperatingSystemMXBean osBean = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMXBean(OperatingSystemMXBean.class);

Double freeRamSize = (double) osBean.getFreePhysicalMemorySize();
Double totalRamSize = (double) osBean.getTotalPhysicalMemorySize();

System.out.println(freeRamSize / GiB + " / " + totalRamSize / GiB);
```

`1.8224868774414062 / 3.9995040893554688`

Comment: Indeed, I just tried on a vm on my personnal computer and it works (both your and my code).
I still don't know why I can't retrieve the freeMemory on the vm at my work, but it seems it's not the code fault. Thank you for your help!